# Unexpected token in JSON at position 1024 react native

Tags: android, react-native

I am getting this error on compiling react native project using the expo framework.

I am getting no stack trace on my terminal but this is the error response on expo client.

http://biobekia.com/public/uploads/bekia-orders/20181218225953fsqRKer87zZBoGMsXWEn7gUm7pOFt3Z4.png

http://biobekia.com/public/uploads/bekia-orders/201812182259531cPLOHvayH5qLSw5WiQdnsxs2f01e4ri.png

Comment: The links you provided produce 403 forbidden errors. Please post your code here.

Comment: "Unexpected token in JSON at position" is an error that happens when you're not getting a json response, if that case is possible, then you need to put your JSON parsing call inside a try and catch.

Comment: @mediaguru  
http://biobekia.com/public/uploads/bekia-orders/201812182259531cPLOHvayH5qLSw5WiQdnsxs2f01e4ri.png

Comment: http://biobekia.com/public/uploads/bekia-orders/20181218225953fsqRKer87zZBoGMsXWEn7gUm7pOFt3Z4.png

Comment: Here are the two links on another server hope this helps

Comment: Please post your CODE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason clearing cache and recompiling fixed the issue, maybe it was an encoding issue that resulted in a tofu Character or something like that.